# Why are the improper integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{n}x\,\mathrm{d}x$ different?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, infinity

> Why are the improper integrals
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,\mathrm{d}x \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{n}x\,\mathrm{d}x$$
> different?

This is question #11.4 from the 2015 ANPEC Exam. It's originally presented with an equality and the official answer is "False". There is no further context on the solution, so I'd like some help with the intuition behind this conclusion.

The full exam can be accessed [here.](https://www.anpec.org.br/novosite/us/the-anpec-national-admission-test)

Comment: The improper integral on the left side doesn't exist.  The limit on the right side is $0$.  Do you know how we define the improper integrals of continuous functions?

Comment: You can think of it like this: in what manner are we approaching infinity in the first integral? We don't know. Thinking in terms of the second integral, we can have the boundaries of integration -n and 2n or -n and n^2 etc. in both cases the the boundaries approach infinity when taking the limits but all the results are different.

Comment: @akujack your answer was very helpful! Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the left integral, by definition, diverges, whereas the right limit is equal to zero.

The definition for the left integral, as is probably cited in the your textbook, is given by

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \, \mathrm{d} x := \lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^c x \, \mathrm{d} x + \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_c^b x \, \mathrm{d} x$$

for any $c$ of your choice satisfying $-\infty < c < \infty$. For this integral to exist, both of these limits must exist; however, neither is finite for this limit, and it is easy to see why.

---

Loosely, I like to think of this as meaning that you need to account for all possible ways or speeds at which the bounds can go off to infinity. For instance, it is fine to say

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \lim_{\substack{a \to -\infty \\ b \to +\infty}} \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

because this handles that. Letting $a=-b$ however is restricting on this and forces them to go to infinity at the same rate.

Answer (score -2):

The first one is a $[\infty-\infty]$ type
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}x\mathrm{d}x=\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}=\infty-\infty\;\Rightarrow \text{indeterminate from}$$
The second is the definition of Cauchy principal value of the first integral
$$\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\mathrm{d}x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}x\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_{x=-n}^{x=+n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n^2}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$$